# Textjoin with Filter Down a Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

Textjoin and filter by values down a column, not in one cell.

I want to join on one row per each unique value in column N on the other sheet.  Here is an example of my input data on the other sheet (Sheet2):

```
Column A (Version), Column N (Value)
1.1  ValueA
1.1  ValueB
1.3  ValueD
1.3  ValueA
1.2  ValueC
1.4  ValueB
```

I would like this result generated through an automatic filter, not a VBA formula, or copying and pasting per unique value in Column B (Sheet1) / Column N (Sheet2)

```
Column A, Column B
1.1, 1.3  ValueA
1.1, 1.4  ValueB
1.3       ValueD
1.2       ValueC
```

I use this formula in A2 and get this result:

```
=TEXTJOIN(“, “,TRUE,INDEX(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A,MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(‘Sheet2’!$N:$N,<‘Sheet2’!$A:$A<>”Column A”)*(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A>0))),‘Sheet2’!$N:$N,0),0)
```

```
Column A,                     Column B
1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4. ValueA
                              ValueB
                              ValueD
                              ValueA
                              ValueC
                              ValueB
```

I use this formula in A2 and get the correct result but I have to annoyingly copy and paste the formula down the column:

```
=TEXTJOIN(“, “,TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A,(((‘Sheet2’!$N:$N=$B2)
```

```
Column A,                     Column B
1.1, 1.3                      ValueA
                              ValueB
                              ValueD
                              ValueA
                              ValueC
                              ValueB
```

I use this formula in A2 and get #N/A value:

```
=TEXTJOIN(“, “,TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A,(((‘Sheet2’$N:$N=(UNIQUE(FILTER(‘Sheet2’!$N:$N,(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A<>”Column A”)*(‘Sheet2’!$A:$A>0)))))))))
```

Does anyone have a formula that can automatically filter the results I would like in the second chart without using VBA or copying and pasting.  I want these results to be auto-populated once entered in cell A2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use BYROW() referencing the unique list.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on how to incorporate that into my formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BYROW on the Unique values:

```
=LET(
    vro,A:A,
    vlo,B:B,
    vr,DROP(FILTER(vro,vro<>""),1),
    vl,DROP(FILTER(vlo,vro<>""),1),
    uq,UNIQUE(vl),
    txt,BYROW(uq,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(vr,vl=a)))),
    HSTACK(txt,uq))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Only an alternative approach using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> and assuming `Column A` can be taken as the column for the last row.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     lastrow, MATCH(7^89,1/(A:A<>"")),
     x, A2:INDEX(A:B,lastrow,),
     y, TAKE(x,,1),
     z, TAKE(x,,-1),
     w, UNIQUE(z),
     HSTACK(MAP(w,LAMBDA(d,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(y,d=z)))),w))
```

---

Comment: I am curious. Why `7^89`?

Comment: Yes, I can use `2` as well or `9^99` as well, when getting the last row number in `MATCH()` function with `1/(A:A<>"")`

Comment: I would have used `2` as it would be one less operation.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, I agree with you, but I learnt this trick from @Jos Wooley Sir, so i used in this way, but yes using `2` is also correct and would be less operation, agree with you completely thank you for sharing

Comment: I use a very large number if I am looking at numeric values that are unknown.  And then I'll use something like `9.9E+307`. But with this kind of comparison, the largest number will be `1`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, but i got all `1`s so using `2` will be right as you said. shouldnt be? Understood clearly now sir !

Comment: Exactly. Using `2`

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I think this is a solid formula:

```
=LET(
    num, D2:D7,
    val, E2:E7,
    uv, UNIQUE(val),
    HSTACK(
        MAP(uv, LAMBDA(m, TEXTJOIN(", ", , FILTER(num, (val = m))))),
        uv
    )
)
```

[image]